# Liferay Mobile Device Detection

Tags: liferay-7, mobile-devices, adaptive-design

I'm new to Liferay, I've downloaded the Mobile Device Detection Lite from Liferay marketplace and put it in the deploy folder and after restarting the server i'm getting the following error

```
ERROR [Framework Event Dispatcher: Equinox Container: 58db3900-d87a-41e5-b86f-6542cbc57b6c][Framework:93] FrameworkEvent ERROR
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.liferay.portal.mobile.device.detection.fiftyonedegrees [2720]_  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.liferay.portal.kernel.mobile.device; version="[8.0.0,8.1.0)"_ [Sanitized]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:444)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1682)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1662)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1624)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1555)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

Can someone please help me with resolving the above issue.

PS: I'm using Liferay version : liferay-ce-portal-7.3.5-ga6

Comment: Indeed I could reproduce this issue with Liferay Mobile Device Detection Lite.lpkg  version 3.0.0 on Liferay CE 7.3.5-ga6.
On Liferay Marketplace, there was this warning message though:
"Final Version: No new versions will be available for this app. Support for this app will end at the EOSL date."

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution!
At first I tried a hacky way that is not recommended:
I modified these values inside com.liferay.portal.mobile.device.detection.fiftyonedegrees-4.0.8.jar  -  MANIFEST.MF :
com.liferay.portal.kernel.mobile.device;version="
[6.0,9.1)",com.liferay.portal.kernel.util;version="[6.12,11)"

to make the jar file deployable, however this method should not be used.

The recommended solution is to download: 
com.liferay.portal.mobile.device.detection.fiftyonedegrees-5.0.8.jar  from  
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.liferay/com.liferay.portal.mobile.device.detection.fiftyonedegrees/5.0.8  and deploy it.